# How can i put an image as bg in Label widget so that the text is also visible

Tags: python, tkinter

Actually the text **THIS IS NOT VISIBLE** is covered by the image.

```
image_caption = Label(canvas, text='THIS IS NOT VISIBLE', fg='brown', image=bg_image)
image_caption.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=100)
```

I want to keep text on an image so that **image** become bg of text instead of **default white** bg.

Comment: You need to set the `compound` option.  See the [document](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this `compound = BOTTOM` or `compound = CENTER` as an argument inside of Button()

```
image_caption = Label(canvas, text='THIS IS NOT VISIBLE', fg='brown',compound=CENTER, image=bg_image)
image_caption.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=100)
```